# Telerik Silverlight RadGridView - need to click buttons twice

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I have a Silverlight UserControl with a Telerik RadGridView control and a handful of button controls.  The problem is that when I edit a cell in the grid view and then click any of the buttons the button command does not execute until; the button is selected a second time.  The first press seems to remove the focus from the RadGridView and second succeeds in firing the bound command.  Obviously, this makes for a terrible user interface.  Does anyone know what might be going on here?

With the exception of the UI behavior everything else works fine.

Simplified XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
  <Button Content="Close" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
</StackPanel>
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding StockItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     IsFilteringAllowed="False"
                     ShowGroupPanel="False">
  <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding LabelGroup,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Header="Label Group" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Message,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Header="Message" />
  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Thanks in advance,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is already fixed - you can check this thread for more info:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/why-do-we-need-to-click-twice-on-a-button-within-a-radgridview.aspx